# Should I add broth to the bottom of the Dutch Oven?

Tags: chicken, roast, dutch-oven, rotisserie

I am roasting a chicken in a dutch oven. Should I add any type of liquid to the bottom of the dutch oven before putting it in the oven?

[image: Moroccan Chicken]

Answer (score 2):

If braising, yes. If roasting (lid off), no.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture above there are vegetables, some will do fine being roasted dry like the carrots and potatoes, but there are some which may not do well like what looks like cabbage. I would add stock and cover to get the best results, then thicken the liquid later for a sauce.